# Как сделать пароль в программе на Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Надо, чтобы когда запускаете программу, вводите пароль в Edit1 и нажимаете на кнопку пароль, сверяется из файла, если он правильный, то показывается сообщение: пароль верен. 
Если неправильный, то показывается сообщение: пароль не верен. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если пароль будет храниться в файле, то это даёт очень мало толку от пароля. По крайней мере он должен быть хотя-бы в зашифрованном виде, а файл должен лежать в какой-нибудь папке, куда нет доступа пользователю. Или записать пароль в реестр. Надо только прочитать пароль и сверить что-ли?

Comment: Мне все ровно

Comment: Тогда, сейчас напишу пример.

Comment: пароль храните в реестре в зашифрованном виде,лучше использовать 
Password Dialog.

Comment: Можно хранить не пароль а хэш от него (например MD5), потом брать хэш от введенного пароля и сравнивать с хэшем настоящего: [Википедия: Криптографическая хэш-функция, проверка парольной фразы][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Криптографическая_хеш-функция#Проверка_парольной_фразы

Comment: > Можно хранить не пароль а хэш от него

Не можно, а нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой (довольно простой) пример:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Pass, p: String;
  FF:  TextFile;

begin
  AssignFile(FF, 'pass.txt');
  Try
    Reset(FF);
    Read(FF, Pass);
  Finally
    CloseFile(FF);
  End;

  If (InputQuery('Ввод пароля', 'пароль', p)) Then
    If (p<>Pass) Then
      Application.Terminate
    Else
      Form1.Show
  Else
    Begin
      MessageBox('Неверный пароль!');
      Application.Terminate;
    End;
end;
```

Минус в том, что при вводе пароля символы показываются нормально, а не звёздочками. Это можно доработать с помощью дополнительной формы.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим,что при запуске программы в memo1 (пусть парол ьк проге будет в текстовом фале...но только например в другом формате! .syt)

```
Memo1.Visible:=false;
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile ('lol.syt');
```

Сверяем с эдитом:

```
if edit1.text=memo1.lines then // или как там
begin
Form2.Show // сама программа
end
else
ShowMessage ('Не верный пароль!');
```

З.Ы. Код писал наспех - возможны ошибки (пунктуационные =)

Comment: `.syt`, в данном случае, не формат файла, а всего лишь расширение.

Answer (score 0):

С реестром можно сделать примерно так

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, registry, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, Buttons, StdCtrls; //подключаем  registry

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Edit1: TEdit;//для ввода пароль юзером
        Edit2: TEdit;//скрытый для загрузки пароля из реестра
        SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;//кнопка для проверки правильности пароля
        Edit3: TEdit;//для того чтобы задать новый пароль
        SpeedButton2: TSpeedButton; //кнопка для того что бы задать новый пароль
        procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
        procedure SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
      var
    RegIniFile:TRegIniFile; //обяъявляем переменную
    begin
     regIniFile:=TRegIniFile.Create('Password');//создаём

    Edit2.Text:=RegIniFile.ReadString('R','A',form1.Edit2.Text);//читаем

    reginifile.Free ;//уничтожаем

    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
      var
    RegIniFile:TRegIniFile; //обяъявляем переменную

    begin
     RegIniFile:=TRegIniFile.Create('Password');// создаём

    RegIniFile.WriteString('R','A',Edit2.text);//пишем

    reginifile.free;//уничтожаем

    end;

    procedure TForm1.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
      var
    RegIniFile:TRegIniFile; //обяъявляем переменную

    begin
     RegIniFile:=TRegIniFile.Create('Password');// создаём
    Edit2.Text:=Edit3.Text;//вводим в Edit2 текст edit3
    RegIniFile.WriteString('R','A',Edit3.text);//пишем новый пароль

    reginifile.free;//уничтожаем

    end;

    procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    {проверяем пароль}
    if edit1.text=edit2.Text then
    ShowMessage('Пароль введён верно')
    else
    ShowMessage('Неверный пароль')
    end;

    end.
```

Первый пароль естественно будет пустым.

Comment: скинь исходник

Comment: Повторюсь, лучше использовать не шифрование, а криптографическую хэш-функцию, это похоже на шифрование, только необратимое. А любое обратимое шифрование ломается путем дизассемблирования бинарника.

Comment: @insolor, тогда уж сразу стоит добавить, что перед хэшированием к паролю нужно добавить соль, иначе пароль легко будет подобрать по радужным таблицам )